# convert all integer columns to float

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have around 30 integer columns and I would like to convert all existing integer columns to float data type.

As of now, I managed to convert only one column at a time.

I have tried this code but couldn't succeed.

```
select CAST(sales,duration AS float) FROM tableName
```

Is it possible to do this in BigQuery?

Comment: One cast per column! But why do you store data in integer columns if you want to display float?

Comment: i have loaded the data using `--autodetect` in bq command line .It loaded some columns as integer.So,I want to convert all of them to float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this in bigquery?

Yes, You can use [DML command](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_table_statement) to change the structure of your table
For example:

```
#standardSQL
 CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE mydataset.newtable (
         field0 FLOAT64, 
         field1 FLOAT64, 
         field2 FLOAT64)
 OPTIONS(
   description="a table with new FLOAT fields",
   labels=[("org_unit", "development")]
 )
```

After you did this you can select from the table without using `cast`

If you have many columns and it's difficult to build the list you have two options to speed this up:

**option 1:**
use `bq show` command to get all the columns (You can use BigQuery shell if you don't have `bq` install locally)

```
bq show --format=prettyjson --schema datasetId.tableId
```

This will output all your columns in this format:

```
{
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "ProvisionedThroughput",
    "type": "STRING"
  }
```

You can take this output and use any editor you like to create the right syntax to the `CREATE OR REPLACE`

**Option 2:**

If you are subscribed to BigQuery [INFORMATION_SCHEMA beta](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#getting_information_about_tables) you can simply select from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA all your fields as follow:

```
WITH ColumnNames AS
  (SELECT COLUMN_NAME,
          data_type
   FROM datasetId.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
   WHERE TABLE_NAME = "tables" )
SELECT CONCAT(ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY (SELECT CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME, ' ', 'FLOAT64') FROM ColumnNames), ' \n'), ')');
```

Which returns an array as follow ready for use:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but,i have 200 integer columns to be converted to float and it is difficult to mention all columns in above query...is there any workaround?

Comment: @NikhilBOORLA I edit my answer to help you overcome the 200 columns issue... I see they are rapidly growing from your original 30 :)

Comment: @NikhilBOORLA If my answer was helpful please consider accepting it, this is how: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235